# Data is being sent via $http to php file but JSON decodes blank or undefined?

Tags: php, angularjs, angular-http

I am using $http through AngularJS to send data to a PHP document which is intended to save the data in a MySQL database. However, the data is being decoded blank or undefined. The JSON makes it to the PHP file, as I can see the request headers, but the response is blank.

I have tried testing different variations of the code to make sure that the JSON-encoded data makes it to the PHP document, and it does, but when attempting to `json_decode()` it does not pull anything from the JSON.

PHP File

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$user = $request->Username;
echo $user;
```

AngularJS

```
$scope.submit = function() {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.walkermediadesign.com/planner3/src/ceremony.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: this.ceremony
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.error = response.statusText;
    })};
```

This is the post data:

```
$postdata = 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Username: "redphyre@gmail.com"}
1: {opening: "Friends and Family of BRIDE and GROOM, welcome and…d 
falling in love with each other all over again."}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

There are no error messages or 500 errors, just blank data being returned.

Comment: missed a `;` so I fixed that, but that wasn't the problem either.

Comment: I guess if I change `$request` to `$request[0]` it fixed the problem though I'm not sure why I needed to do that?

Comment: Request is an array of objects. the first object holds the Username, the second holds opening. You could simplify that structure if you have control over the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were expecting JSON data that looked like this:

```
{
    "Username": "redphyre@gmail.com",
    "opening": "Friends and Family..."
}
```

Where you have a single object with all the expected properties.

What you are actually getting, however, is this:

```
[
    { "Username": "redphyre@gmail.com" },
    { "opening": "Friends and Family..." }
]
```

That creates an array of objects, each with only one property, which is not nearly as easy to work with. To convert the data to a single object with multiple properties, you can loop though your result set:

```
$responseData = new stdClass();

foreach ($response as $propertyObject) {
    $properties = get_object_vars($propertyObject);

    // Just in case some objects have more than one property after all
    foreach($properties as $name => $value) {
        $responseData->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

That will copy the individual properties of the objects in the response array into a single object.